# Why doesn't my Intent work?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have the following code:

```
public class P1R1 extends Activity {

    int correctCounter;
    private String[] answerString;
    private TextView score;
    private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
    protected static final String EXTRA_playerOneScore = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.level);

        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);

        correctCounter = 0;

        loadActivity();
        //start round timer
        new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

            final TextView timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);


            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timer.setText("Time: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000 + "s");
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                Intent roundOneToTwo = new Intent(getActivity(), R1R2.class);
                String playerOneScore = String.valueOf(correctCounter);
                roundOneToTwo.putExtra(EXTRA_playerOneScore, playerOneScore);
                startActivity(roundOneToTwo);
            }
         }.start();
```

I have a timer running, and when the timer is over I want the `Intent` to run, but I'm getting an error for my Intent saying `The constructor Intent(new CountDownTimer(){}, Class<R1R2>) is undefined`.

I did create an R1R2 class, but my Intent is still giving an error. I'm still new to android, so it would be great if you could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of

```
Intent roundOneToTwo = new Intent(this, R1R2.class);
```

try

```
Intent roundOneToTwo = new Intent(P1R1.this, R1R2.class);
```

First parameter to Intent constructor should be the Context, but you're passing reference to the CountDownTimer. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: Now it gives me the error "The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new CountDownTimer(){}"

Comment: What class/UI element instantiates the CountDownTimer? Do you have a reference to a Context or Activity somewhere, perhaps in a local variable?

Comment: The name of the class is P1R1

Comment: Oh - I see it. Use P1R1.this as the first parameter